# Rundeck Oracle Integration : ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

Tags: rundeck

I am working on Rundeck POC for migrating jobs from Jenkins. But when I used oracle as backend to the rundeck I am getting the following exception:

Rundeck version: Rundeck 3.1.2-20190927

### "/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties" file entry for dialect:

dataSource.dialect=org.rundeck.hibernate.RundeckOracleDialect

### Dialect Jar:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/rundeck/hibernate/rundeck-oracle-dialect/1.0.0/rundeck-oracle-dialect-1.0.0.jar

## Exception during rundeck start-up:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:931)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1792)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:334)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
```

Comment: Can you share the content of your rundeck-config.properties file to take a look? please add this line: hibernate.show_sql=true (on rundeck-config.properties) to see what happens while Rundeck starts.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rundeck 3, the Oracle Dialect is out of the box, just need to configure the database and Rundeck to use it. For example, the following config at rundeck-config.properties works without adding nothing special (only the oracle JDBC at /var/lib/rundeck/lib directory)

```
dataSource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.33.30:1521:xe
dataSource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
dataSource.username = rundeckuser
dataSource.password = rundeckpass
dataSource.dialect = org.rundeck.hibernate.RundeckOracleDialect
dataSource.properties.validationQuery = SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

Take a look at this:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/oracle.html